# Why tailwind key is missing?

Tags: tailwind-css, tailwind-in-js, tailwind-ui

I don't understand why I have this issue

warn - The `content` key is missing or empty. Please populate the content key as Tailwind generates utilities on-demand based on the files that use them. For more information see the documentation: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration

tailwind.config.js

```js
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

Comment: Please include your `tailwind.config.js` file.

Comment: module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}

Comment: Where's the html files?

Comment: I don't understand sorry

Comment: Any success on this? Run in the same issue today.

Answer (score 1):

I found that updating js -> jsx like below brought success.

```js
module.exports = {
  content: ["./src/**/*.{html,jsx}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try adding this

```
purge: {
    enabled: true,
    content: [
        './**/*.html'
    ]
  },
content: ["./src/**/*.{html,jsx}"],
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to link your html to the content. For now, delete all that you got there and try to link only the html file. Later, feel free to put there other files.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).